# Cannot change working directory to folder in windows through R in Ubuntu command line

Tags: r, shell, ubuntu, windows-10

I have had to install Ubuntu command line on windows10 in order to install R and download a package that is not supported on R for windows. This has worked fine, however, I need to set the working directory in R to the folder containing the files the package needs to work with. I have looked at lots of forums about changing directory and I have no luck!

My default working directory is a hidden folder created by windows when I installed ubuntu command line. I can access this, but I dont need this folder...I need to change the working directory in R to a folder on the D drive on my computer. I have tried to no avail!!

I have tried the normal setwd() command with the following combinations, all of which return the error 'cannot change working directory'

setwd("D:/RNA-seq data/")

setwd("d:/RNA-seq)

setwd("~D:/RNA-seq)

I am really frustrated that I cannot carry out this simple command (maybeI am doing something fundamentally wrong) or maybe this is a limitation because of the hidden default home folder set by windows? Please not I cannot transfer the necessary files in to the default folder created by windows for 'home/R' as it is on the C drive and there isnt enough space on disk. I need to navigate to the folder on d drive in order to carry out my code!!

Any help would be really really appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: When you run R, are you running it as superuser, i.e. `sudo r `?

Comment: No! Just R and enter... Would this make a difference?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1066261/how-to-access-windows-folders-from-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows - you need to use `/mnt/d` instead of trying to use Windows path names. So the code would likely need to be `setwd('/mnt/d/RNA-seq/')`

Comment: Thank you so so much!! This has worked!! mnt/d/RNA-seq data changes directory succesfully within R. And thank you for linking the other post!! May I ask what the purpose of 'mnt' is?

Comment: `/mnt/` is a traditional path on Unixish OSes where other file systems are mounted.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your assistance! that worked perfectly and my code is successfully running! and thank you all for the quick replies!